# How to split and send data >20 bytes for BLE in Xamarin forms?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to implement **BLE in Xamarin forms**. I want to **send data** larger than 20 bytes. I have seen the implementations in the native android using java. It looks like below

```
private void sendMessage(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, String CHARACTERS){
        byte[] initial_packet = new byte[3];
        /**
         * Indicate byte
         */
        initial_packet[0] = BLE.INITIAL_MESSAGE_PACKET;
        if (Long.valueOf(
                String.valueOf(CHARACTERS.length() + initial_packet.length))
                > BLE.DEFAULT_BYTES_VIA_BLE) {
            sendingContinuePacket(characteristic, initial_packet, CHARACTERS);
        } else {
            sendingLastPacket(characteristic, initial_packet, CHARACTERS);
        }
    }

private void sendingContinuePacket(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
            byte[] initial_packet, String CHARACTERS){
        /**
         * TODO If data length > Default data can sent via BLE : 20 bytes
         */
        // Check the data length is large how many times with Default Data (BLE)
        int times = Byte.valueOf(String.valueOf(
                CHARACTERS.length() / BLE.DEFAULT_BYTES_IN_CONTINUE_PACKET));

        Log.i(TAG, "CHARACTERS.length() " + CHARACTERS.length());
        Log.i(TAG, "times " + times);

        // TODO
        // 100 : Success
        // 101 : Error
        byte[] sending_continue_hex = new byte[BLE.DEFAULT_BYTES_IN_CONTINUE_PACKET];
        for (int time = 0; time <= times; time++) {
            /**
             * Wait second before sending continue packet 
             */
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (time == times) {
                Log.i(TAG, "LAST PACKET ");

                /**
                 * If you do not have enough characters to send continue packet,
                 * This is the last packet that will be sent to the band
                 */

                /**
                 * Packet length byte :
                 */
                /**
                 * Length of last packet
                 */
                int character_length = CHARACTERS.length()
                        - BLE.DEFAULT_BYTES_IN_CONTINUE_PACKET*times;

                initial_packet[1] = Byte.valueOf(String.valueOf(character_length
                        + BLE.INITIAL_MESSAGE_PACKET_LENGTH));
                initial_packet[2] = BLE.SENDING_LAST_PACKET;

                Log.i(TAG, "character_length " + character_length);

                /**
                 * Message
                 */
                // Hex file
                byte[] sending_last_hex = new byte[character_length];

                // Hex file : Get next bytes
                for (int i = 0; i < sending_last_hex.length; i++) {
                    sending_last_hex[i] = 
                            CHARACTERS.getBytes()[sending_continue_hex.length*time + i];
                }

                // Merge byte[]
                byte[] last_packet = 
                        new byte[character_length + BLE.INITIAL_MESSAGE_PACKET_LENGTH];
                System.arraycopy(initial_packet, 0, last_packet,
                        0, initial_packet.length);
                System.arraycopy(sending_last_hex, 0, last_packet, 
                        initial_packet.length, sending_last_hex.length);

                // Set value for characteristic
                characteristic.setValue(last_packet);
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "CONTINUE PACKET ");
                /**
                 * If you have enough characters to send continue packet,
                 * This is the continue packet that will be sent to the band
                 */
                /**
                 * Packet length byte
                 */
                int character_length = sending_continue_hex.length;

                /**
                 * TODO Default Length : 20 Bytes
                 */
                initial_packet[1] = Byte.valueOf(String.valueOf(
                        character_length + BLE.INITIAL_MESSAGE_PACKET_LENGTH));

                /**
                 * If sent data length > 20 bytes (Default : BLE allow send 20 bytes one time)
                 * -> set 01 : continue sending next packet
                 * else or if after sent until data length < 20 bytes
                 * -> set 00 : last packet
                 */
                initial_packet[2] = BLE.SENDING_CONTINUE_PACKET;
                /**
                 * Message
                 */
                // Hex file : Get first 17 bytes
                for (int i = 0; i < sending_continue_hex.length; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Send stt : " 
                            + (sending_continue_hex.length*time + i));

                    // Get next bytes
                    sending_continue_hex[i] = 
                            CHARACTERS.getBytes()[sending_continue_hex.length*time + i];
                }

                // Merge byte[]
                byte[] sending_continue_packet = 
                        new byte[character_length + BLE.INITIAL_MESSAGE_PACKET_LENGTH];
                System.arraycopy(initial_packet, 0, sending_continue_packet, 
                        0, initial_packet.length);
                System.arraycopy(sending_continue_hex, 0, sending_continue_packet, 
                        initial_packet.length, sending_continue_hex.length);

                // Set value for characteristic
                characteristic.setValue(sending_continue_packet);
            }

            // Write characteristic via BLE
            mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }
    }

public boolean writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
            String data) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return false;
        }

        if (ActivityBLEController.IS_FIRST_TIME) {
            /**
             * In the first time, 
             * should send the Title
             */
            byte[] merge_title = sendTitle(data);

            // Set value for characteristic
            characteristic.setValue(merge_title);

            // Write characteristic via BLE
            mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);

            // Reset
            ActivityBLEController.IS_FIRST_TIME = false;

            return true;
        } else {
            /**
             * In the second time, 
             * should send the Message
             */
            if (data.length() <= BLE.LIMIT_CHARACTERS) {
                sendMessage(characteristic, data);

                // Reset
                ActivityBLEController.IS_FIRST_TIME = true; 

                return true;
            } else {
                // Typed character
                typed_character = data.length();

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my **Xamarin code** where I do write operation

```
 private async Task<string> ReadAndWriteCharacterisicsValue(ICharacteristic _characteristics)
        {
            if (_characteristics != null)
            {
                var sbnew = new StringBuilder("BLE Characteristics\n");
                byte[] senddata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.IsNullOrEmpty("") ? "Hi1290004847846767627723676" : "");

                if (MainThread.IsMainThread)
                {
                    string writeTypes = _characteristics.WriteType.ToString();
                    await _characteristics.WriteAsync(senddata);

                }

                //_characteristics.ReadAsync();


                var charVal = _characteristics.Value;

                var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(charVal);
                sbnew.AppendLine($"Characteristics found on this device: {string.Join(", ", str.ToString())}");

                return sbnew.ToString();


            }
            return null;
        }
```

When I try to send String **Hi1290004847846767627723676(27 Bytes)** but I get **Hi129000484784676762(20 Bytes)** in peripheral **without crashing**. I'm using **plugin.ble** latest version and also my bluetooth device version is **5.0**. **I even tried requesting Mtu**. As you can see in the following code

```
 if (_characteristics != null)
            {
                try
                {

                    var sbnew = new StringBuilder("BLE Characteristics\n");
                     byte[] senddata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.IsNullOrEmpty("") ? "Start{'command':'UnSelectEnhancement','data':[{'UnSelectEnhancement':'VitaminC'},{'UnSelectEnhancement':'CitricAcid'},  {'UnSelectEnhancement':'Electolytes'},{'UnSelectEnhancement':'Sweetener'}]}End":"");
                   
                    await _device.RequestMtuAsync(2000);
                  

                    
                    if (MainThread.IsMainThread)
                    {
                        string writeTypes = _characteristics.WriteType.ToString();
                         await _characteristics.WriteAsync(senddata);

                    }
```

I want to send data maximum of **200 bytes**. I also tried **splitting string** using this code.

```
IEnumerable<string> s = str.Split();
                    IEnumerable<string> Split( )
                    {
                        while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
                        {
                            var chunk = str.Take(size).ToArray();
                           str = str.Substring(chunk.Length);
                           yield return new string(chunk);

                       }

                    }

                    
                    Console.WriteLine("Error of split");
                    
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, str));
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, str));
```

But it didn't work.It looks quite complicated for me. **Is there any easy way** to do the write operation for data larger than **20 bytes using c# in xamarin forms**?

Comment: What version of BLE are you using? 4.2+ allows more than 20bytes to be sent in one message

Comment: @M.Kotzjan I'm using Latest Plugin.BLE version 2.1.1 in my application. I can't find any other BLE plugin with 4.2+ version in xamarin forms.

Comment: @M.Kotzjan This is the plugin I'm using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.BLE

Comment: The plugin should support at least all features of 4.2 if not more. The BLE version depends on the BLE version of your devices. All modern smartphones are capable of at least v4.2. TO use the features of v4.2 the peripheral needs to support 4.2 as well. If thats the case you should be able to ask for a higher MTU to send larger messages

Comment: @M.Kotzjan My peripheral device is Redmi 9A and client device is Redmi note 8 both has bluetooth version 5.0.

Comment: @M.Kotzjan My app is not crashing when I am doing write operation but only 20 bytes of data is send to peripheral at a time. for example when I try to send Hi1290004847846767627723676 I get Hi129000484784676762 in peripheral.

Comment: This is probably caused by the MTU being set to 20. I had a quick look but I did not find anything in Plugin.BLE that allows the request of an higher MTU.

Comment: @M.Kotzjan ok so with which plugin can I achieve this?

Comment: https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle looks like it supports mtu requests

Comment: @M.Kotzjan I used aritchie plugin before, it also doesn't support transfer of data larger than 20 Bytes.

Comment: @M.Kotzjan If I can split strings based on bytes and send it. It will be useful for me. That is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I understand. Setting the MTU to a higher value would solve that problem without splitting your data.

Comment: Have a look at this discussion from your plugin: https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le/issues/128 and this function for android: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.bluetooth.bluetoothgatt.requestmtu?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

Comment: @M.Kotzjan I tried adding code await _device.RequestMtuAsync(2000); but it still sends 20 Bytes.

Comment: I can only assume 2000 is way to large. Try something realistic like 251, the maximum for BLE 4.2. If that does not work I've got no more clues

Comment: @M.Kotzjan Yes I'll try that. Am I using correct approach to request MTU. I'm just using single code await _device.RequestMtuAsync(2000);.Do I need to add extra code to get it working. And do I need to do something in peripheral side aswell?

Comment: @M.Kotzjan I tried setting 251. It didn't work.

Comment: @Judson Abraham, have a look at my answer. That code sends your data in chunks with a maximum size of 20 bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try and send the data in multiple chunks each having a maximum size of 20.
This example sends the first chunk of 20 bytes, then another one with the remaining 7.

```
            byte[] senddata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hi1290004847846767627723676");
            int start = 0;
            while (start < senddata.Length)
            {
                int chunkLength = Math.Min(20, senddata.Length - start);
                byte[] chunk = new byte[chunkLength];
                Array.Copy(senddata, start, chunk, 0, chunkLength);
                await writeBuf.WriteAsync(chunk);
                start += 20;
            }
```

*Edits:*

- Removed comment which was copy & pasted