# Request MTU is not working in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy, mtu

I'm implementing BLE in Xamarin forms where I'm trying to send data larger than 20 bytes. So I used

```
await _device.RequestMtuAsync(512);
```

It works in my Redmi Note 8 device but some devices like Samsung and Honor it fails. I went through some native android solutions so there they are trying to do this operation in loop as you can see in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149114/request-mtu-is-not-working-in-nougat). I want to implement same thing in Xamarin forms but I don't have any clue how to implement this in c# code any suggestions?

Comment: What specifically don't you understand?  That appears to be a simple while() loop

Comment: @Jason Where does this mtuRequestCounter++; comes from.

Comment: @Jason can u convert it to c# code and answer it for better understanding.

Comment: @Jason Even I don't know how to get mtuConfirmed boolean for RequestMtuAsync.

Comment: RequestMtuAsync returns the negotiated MTU apparently: https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le/blob/9d4ec4d4f718971a1aac0ef8bf986b8bfa492de9/Source/BLE.Client/BLE.Client/ViewModels/DeviceListViewModel.cs#L469 You could check if the returned value equals 512

Comment: @M.Kotzjan I'm going to do write in chunks instead of MTU because MTU doesn't work for some devices properly.

Comment: So I'm going to use the approach in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65246453/how-to-split-and-send-data-20-bytes-for-ble-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: Glad you found a solution for your problem!